# define('WP_DEBUG', true); does not show errors

Tags: php, wordpress

I enabled the errors in my wp-config file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

But I have an empty white page. No errors are listed.

Comment: check your error log, it describes all the errors

Comment: where is the log file?

Comment: @AntonioMorales The WordPress debug log file is called debug.log and it is created in the /wp-content/ WordPress subdirectory.

Answer (score 33):

The below code, inserted in your wp-config.php file, will log all errors, notices, and warnings to a file called debug.log in the wp-content directory. It will also hide the errors so they do not interrupt page generation.

**this code you must have to insert BEFORE /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */ in the wp-config.php file.**

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

source: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: is it have write permission for wp-content directory becx it need to create a  log(debug.log) file there

Comment: yes, all files and folder wordpress have 777 permission

Comment: me too,... it's not working... I have migrated to my local laptop using XAMPP but ended up with blank white screen... any ideas?

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately

Comment: Try plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/issues-tracker/ or do everything as described in the documentation https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 13):

Add these two lines below the

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

then delete them when you don't need them any more.

Comment: It's working for me.. Upvote from my side.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Plugins or themes that are using PHP's `set_exception_handler()` ([see the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)) can also cause errors to not be shown, because their callback might just silently ignore the error. For example, I experienced the exact same thing using NextGen Gallery, but once I deactivated it, errors appeared as normal on both the page and in the `debug.log` file.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to check is the `WP_CONTENT_DIR` variable as that is where the `debug.log` file would be put. It may be checked as suggested in [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13063/how-to-inspect-global-variables-in-wordpress), or using the Wordfence plugin->Tools->Diagnostics->WordPress Settings. Normally it is not explicitly set unless there's a custom configuration. Though it can can be set in `wp-config.php` e.g. `define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/www/sites/wordpress/wp-content');`

Answer (score 1):

You can write this into your .htaccess file.

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
```

Please change the error_log directory.