# Wordpress functions.php - if condition kills other posts content

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

So I got this code, which I am trying to adapt to my needs. It should and does wrap a div around the necessary `<img> tags`. But when I add the "`if (is_page...)"` all other sites have no content anymore. I am very confused as to why this is happening since the code should not execute or do anything when the if statement is not met.

```
function breezer_addDivToImage( $content ) {
if ( is_page_template('single.php') ) {
   // A regular expression of what to look for.
   $pattern = '/(<img([^>]*)>)/i';
   // What to replace it with. $1 refers to the content in the first 'capture group', in parentheses above
   $replacement = '<div class="myphoto">$1</div>';

   // run preg_replace() on the $content
   $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );

   // return the processed content
   return $content;
}
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'breezer_addDivToImage' );
/* Place custom code above this line. */
?>
```

This is how i display the content on the page

```
<!--S3 show if dynamic page (blogposts)-->
<?php } else if (is_page() == false) {
 if(have_posts()) :
    while(have_posts())  : the_post();
      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
       <img class="responsive-img" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
      <?php } ?>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <?php the_content();
        endwhile;
        else : ?>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
 <?php endif;
} ?>
<!--S3 end "show if dynamic page"-->
```

Comment: you should pass correct path for single.php file in is_page_template('single.php');

Comment: see this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238640/what-does-is-page-template-compare-against

Comment: @GufranHasan This is what I did. And it works for that specified page. But since that code is in the functions file, all other pages have no content anymore. That's my issue. Can you help on this one?

Comment: Could you write error here?

Comment: @GufranHasan there is no error. The pages Content simply doesn't display.
This is how I show the content on that page (see edit in original post)

Comment: enable debug mode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266155/definewp-debug-true-not-show-errors

Comment: @GufranHasan already done. no errors. (did you see my edit above?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you filter your content of all pages and posts with this hook and only return the content if the condition is true.

Put simply a else {return $content} to your breezer_addDivToImage function.

```
function breezer_addDivToImage( $content ) {
  if ( is_page_template('single.php') ) {
  // A regular expression of what to look for.
  $pattern = '/(<img([^>]*)>)/i';
  // What to replace it with. $1 refers to the content in the first 'capture group', in parentheses above
  $replacement = '<div class="myphoto">$1</div>';

  // run preg_replace() on the $content
  $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );

  // return the processed content
  return $content;
 }
 else {
  return $content;
 }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'breezer_addDivToImage' );
```

Comment: @frizzant dos this help you?

Comment: Perfect! I had the feeling that it was something like this. This greatly improves my understanding of how the functions.php works in WP. Thanks!